# Available authorization modal on swagger-ui is not populated for OIDC security scheme

Tags: openid-connect, swagger-ui, okta, springdoc

Goal: I am trying to make Open ID Connect authentication work for swagger-ui on Spring.

Problem: When I click 'Authorize' button on swagger UI, 'Available authentication' modal is empty.

So far:

I have set up security scheme as suggested in the swagger documentation.
API documentation is generated correctly as following.

```
...

"components": {
  "securitySchemes": {
    "openId": {
      "type": "openIdConnect",
      "openIdConnectUrl": "https://{---}.okta.com/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration" 
    }
  }
}

...

## I have omitted the url on purpose but have confirmed that the GET request succeeds.
```

I read up on similar issues, but most of them points out that swagger-ui for OIDC was not supported prior to 3.38.0. Since I am using springdoc v1.5.2 which has a dependency on swagger-ui v.3.38.0 I don't think this is the cause.

Wondering if anyone out there got things to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I will suggest to open this as an issue here - https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues

Comment: @virendrachaudhary I did. Just in case you want to see the issue here's the link. [#issue-778902911](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1007#issue-778902911)

Comment: Do you also have the `security` section in your API definition? [Example](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/openid-connect-discovery/#how). `security` is used to apply the defined security scheme globally or to individual endpoints.

Comment: You can use v1.5.9 which supports swagger-ui v3.49.0, that has enhanced OIDC support!